# How do I avoid the use of activechart in my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

As shown below, my codes consists of alot of activechart usage which causes my program to be buggy. As I need to create 1 chart each for different worksheet, how do I avoid using activechart and change into something else?

```
Private Sub addgraph_Vramp3()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim i As Long
      Dim wz As Workbook
    Set wz = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim wsz As Worksheet
    Set wsz = wz.Worksheets("current3")
     wsz.Activate
       wsz.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=wsz.Range("A1:BQ701")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.001
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0.000000000000001
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"

    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
   ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.E+00"
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='current'!$B$1"

 For i = 2 To totalsample3 Step 1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = wsz.Range(Cells(2, 2 * i - 1), wsz.Cells(myarray(i + 1), 2 * i - 1))
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = wsz.Range(Cells(2, 2 * i), wsz.Cells(myarray(i + 1), 2 * i))
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = wsz.Cells(1, 2 * i)
Next i



    With ActiveChart
        .Legend.Delete
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Voltage"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Current"
    End With

            ' if TDDB, change to Time. ' if TDDB, change to logscale.
        If testitem = True Then
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time(Seconds)"
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
        Else
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't  use select  statement. Use  Variable. And The with statement simplifies coding.

```
   Dim shp as  shape
   Dim Cht as  Chart

   Set shp = wsz.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers,200,300,250,500)
   Set Cht = shp.Chart

   With Cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        ' ~~~~~~~  your  code
   End  with
```

Comment: so i replace my activechart with Cht in this case?

Comment: and i suppose i can remove this line " wsz.Shapes.AddChart.Select " and replace it with  Set shp = wsz.Shapes.AddChart will do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `With Cht` ?

Comment: @braX i think you are correct, I jus faced the error on that line

Answer (score 0):

But why is my chart name chart1 even though i didnt mentioned anything about chart 1 in my code? Will this affect how the graph is plotted?
[image]

Comment: When  chart  is created, the  chart is ploted  automatically base on  active sheet cell.  So you must delete all of sriescollection. Then set the chart.